# Android Studio - Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'. - Unresolved supertypes

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies, android-appcompat

I've been tearing my hair out all day trying to understand why I've been getting this error while trying to compile an Android Studio Kotlin/Java project:

```
Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity, unresolved supertypes: android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder.SupportParentable
```

This is compiling on my colleagues' machines no problem and this app is currently in production so I know it works.

This has also resulted in a bunch of other errors in the code. Mostly:

- `Unresolved reference: context`
- `Unresolved reference: create`
- `Unresolved reference: lifecycle`

Running `gradle --dependencies` yields a very large dependency tree but the first few lines jump out at me:

```
easeUnitTestRuntimeClasspath - Resolved configuration for runtime for variant: releaseUnitTest
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:12.0.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1
|         |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1
```

Specifically `+--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1`

I'm not entirely sure this is what's causing the error as there is no mention of a dependency conflict.

I also noticed this which is an internally developed module so it's an easy fix:

```
+--- project :fastgraph
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1
```

Which when resolved makes not difference to the output when trying to compile. As I've mentioned before it compiles fine on other machines so I'm trying to figure out if it's an issue with my setup (Android Studio bug?) or if there is actually something wrong with the dependencies.

Has anyone had an issue like this before? Cheers.